# How to go to a folder in D drive in Anaconda prompt from C drive for Jupyter Lab?

Tags: anaconda3

I want to go to a folder in D Drive in Anaconda prompt from C drive

I tried and succeeded and want to share the results.

1. Open Anaconda prompt
2. Type cd : D\Any folder\ More folder
3. Type D:
4. Type jupyter-lab
5. Press enter
   [C drive to D drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7jF9.png)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open Anaconda prompt
2. Type D:
3. Type cd Any folder\More folder
4. Type jupyter-lab

If you go to drive C again, you will be in the same directory where you were last there and vice versa. @ani's answer is also correct.